# Can I use nmap to discover IPs and mac addresses?

Tags: ip, mac, ip-address, mac-address, nmap

When I need to locate the IPs of devices by their mac address on a
Windows system, I normally use Advanced IP Scanner (from radmin.com)
to scan the network, then I use arp -a to list the mac addresses.

Is it possible to use nmap to perform the same function in Linux and
possibly in Windows? Can nmap to the scanning and produce both IPs and
MAC addresses?

I have tried arp -a in Linux but it doesn't seem to work as quickly as
in Windows or appears to require some use input.

/vfclists

Comment: nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Ping scans, which start with the P-flag. However, I personally use -sL for this job.

http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Comment: +1 I use -sP as well. But attention, to be able to get mac addresses you have to be on the same lan (no routers in between).

Comment: I have tested with the -sP option and it is exactly what I am looking for, thanks to Pier and Iraklis. It is for scanning for items getting their IPs via DHCP or static in the local network.

Answer (score 13):

Using nmap a lot of info can be found..

`nmap -A -v -v 192.168.1.0/24` gives a lot of information, even SO in some cases

`nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` gives the MAC and IP addresses. Very Useful too

`sudo nmap -PU 192.168.1.0/24` explains every IP address

Comment: According to the nmap man page, `-sP` is now known as `-sn`

Answer (score 8):

The following command with *nmap* with *root* privilegies (or using *sudo*):

```
sudo nmap -sP 172.31.201.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print " => "$3;}' | sort
```

results in:

```
172.31.201.80 => 00:50:56:AF:56:FB
172.31.201.97 => 00:26:73:78:51:42
server1.company.internal.local => 3C:D9:2B:70:BC:99
...
```

Comment: This glues lines a lot. The other answer is better: https://serverfault.com/a/669862/284568.

Comment: @Velkan The other answer is missing sudo and also give me only IP : MAC, this answer give you IP/hostname : MAC, everything depends of your needs. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that it needs root privileges.

Answer (score 7):

This commands scans all IP addresses in a range and shows the MAC address of each IP address.
It does this in a greppable format, or in other words; displays IP and MAC address on a single line. Thats handy if you want to export to Excel or run a grep on it.

```
nmap -n -sP 10.0.3.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report/{printf $5;printf " ";getline;getline;print $3;}'
```

It seems to also work for IP's/MAC's which are not already in the hosts ARP table. That's a good thing.

The command results in:

```
10.0.3.100 B8:27:EB:8E:C5:51
10.0.3.101 00:26:B6:E1:4B:EB
10.0.3.112 00:01:29:02:55:25
etc..
```

Comment: For future reference, `-oG -` or similar should be far easier to parse.

Comment: As it turns out, at lease `-oG` doesn't preserve the mac addresses. Wtf?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to antonio-saco's response.  I wanted to also list the vendor as well to the output.  To do that you want to print the 3rd index (MAC address) to the end of the line.

```
sudo nmap -sn 10.10.10.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print " => "substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' | sort
```

Results in:

```
10.10.10.24 => B0:5A:DA:EB:2A:C4 (Hewlett Packard)
```